# Import .obj file by CATIA VBA Macro

Tags: vba, import, .obj, catia

I'm trying to make CATIA VBA Macro that import and open .obj files.

I know how to open .obj file by using 'existing component'.

But I have about k ~ 10k files to handle tasks. I need macro to do those works...

I searched many website and v5automation, but I failed to get adequate information.

Are there anyone have any information to write vba macro about import .obj files in CATIA V5?

Comment: I tried open method, but that method can not open obj files... (Set CATDoc = CATIA.Documents.Open(FilePath)) I want to know is there any method can import obj files by vba macro in catia...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the *AddComponentsFromFiles* Methode from the *Products*-Collection.
(See also the code from the macro recorder)